# Word press:Remove Category from Menu link

Tags: php, wordpress

I am new to word press and want to remove category from menu link.

Example:
When i click `Entertainment` page redirect to 
`http://khabarchar.com/category/entertainment/`
I want to remove `category` from above link.The link should be `http://khabarchar.com/entertainment/`

As I am new to word press,i don't know how can i achieve.

http://khabarchar.com/

Comment: @AryehArmon  i did not find,can you please guide mae more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a plugin for that its called FV Top Level Categories.
It basically does exactly what you are looking for.

http://wordpress.org/plugins/fv-top-level-cats/